# Flex release build issue!

Tags: apache-flex, release

I am trying to finish up my applications but encounter a big problem.. I have 3 applications that will display on different page. ex:product.html will contain product.mxml, new product.html will contain newProduct.mxml,user.html will contain user.mxml....

They are three different projects and I want to put them together in a website. My problem is that I can't put all release build files in the same main folder because the release applications all share the same name..ex:rpc_4.0.0.13363.swf,swfobject.js,gateway.php,framework_4.0.0.13363.swf and bunch of folders. Only the application swf is different. ex:product.swf, newProduct.swf...

I can't put them together under the same main folder. Also, my product application can upload image file into the asset folder UNDER the product application but I also need user application be able to see the image file that was uploaded to the product application.

Again the problem is, I can't put all 3 application together under the same main folder....what can I do?? Please help me! I really need this done. Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please Remove **!!! Plz help!** every question here requires assistance. I assure your question will get the same treatment as any other. Placing that in the title does not add value.

Comment: It's gone now...and thank you for the suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files which are the same are used by all your applications (they are the standard flex libraries) so you should be ok with copying all the swfs which are specific to your code (just the product.swf, newProduct.swf, ...)  to one of the folders, and it should all work.

Comment: yes, I did try that, but when I run my application, I got errors that said my Class file is missing (php service file). I did copy my php files. Thanks for the reply. +1

Comment: well. Turns out I did miss some files to copy. Thanks for the tip :D